# Use ajax in asp.net mvc 5 in a tab

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use ajax to update the content of a TAB and it doesn't work, when I press the buton submit i update all the page. I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks.

**Controller PeticioUsuarisController:**

```
  // POST: PeticioUsuaris/_Demanar
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult _Demanar([Bind(Include = "Nom,PrimerCognom,SegonCognom")] PeticioUsuari peticioUsuari)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                peticioUsuari.IdUsuariFaPeticio = 1;
                db.PeticioUsuari.Add(peticioUsuari);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return PartialView("_PeticioCorrecte");
            }

            return PartialView("_PeticioCorrecte");
        }
```

**View Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}

<!-- Tab Buttons -->
<ul id="tabstrip" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#_Demanar" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Demanar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#_AcceptarPeticio" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Acceptar</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab Content Containers -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="_Demanar">@Html.Partial("_Demanar")</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="_AcceptarPeticio"></div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
    $('#tabstrip a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var tabID = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
        $(".tab-pane").each(function () {
            console.log("clearing " + $(this).attr("id") + " tab");
            $(this).empty();
        });
        //$("#" + tabID).load("/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]/" + tabID)
    $.ajax({
        url: "/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]/" + tabID,
        cache: false,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#" + tabID).html(result);
        }

    })
   $(this).tab('show')
});
    </script>
}
```

**View _Demanar:**

```
@model Peticions.Models.PeticioUsuari

@{
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = "content",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter
    };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Demanar", "PeticioUsuaris", null, options))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal tabs">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimerCognom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrimerCognom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimerCognom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SegonCognom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SegonCognom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SegonCognom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div id="content"></div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**View _PeticioCorrecte:**

```
@model Peticions.Models.PeticioUsuari

<div class="alert alert-success">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "PeticioUsuaris", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional })">
        Petició enviada correctament! Clica aquí per a crear-ne un altre.
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a question? First try it yourself and then post the question about the error that you are receiving. SO is not a code writing service. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry Alo, is my first time... I've tried a lot of times with different methods, and I don't know what can be the next step (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    @{
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = "formContent"
    };
    }    
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_AcceptarPeticio", "PeticioUsuaris", null,options  ))
    {
    }
```